# How to use schedule library in cogs in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, schedule

I want the bot to do a job everyday at a specific time, I know I can do that with schedule and that is pretty simple too. I tried that and that worked but now I am trying to arrange that into cogs and repeatedly getting errors.

cog:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import discord.utils
from discord.utils import get
import schedule
import asyncio
import time

class SmanageCog(commands.Cog, name='Manager') :

    def __init__(self,bot):
        self.bot = bot

    def job(self):
        print("HEY IT'S TIME!")

    schedule.every().day.at("10:00").do(job)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(SmanageCog(bot))
    print("Manager is loaded!")
```

according to the above code, bot would print hey its time at 10 am everyday. But this doesn't work. It throws me error at 10 am .
Error would be like:

```
File "C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 653, in load_extension
    self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 599, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.smanage' raised an error: TypeError: job() missing 1 required positional arguments: 'self'
```

I don't know what argument should I pass from `def job` , I can't leave that empty in a cog and self also gives error so I don't really know what to pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
schedule.every().day.at("10:00").do(job)
```

You are passing in the function/method `job` into the scheduler with no object bound to it.  So when the job runs, the scheduler calls that function as a "naked method", and so it does not provide a `self` argument to the method.

I'm not sure what's going on with you having code at the class level of your SmanageCog definition, but if your code were outside the class definition, you could do something like this:

```
schedule.every().day.at("10:00").do(SmanageCog(bot).job)
```

and then you'd be providing a bound method to the scheduler and it would have an object to pass as `self` to the method.

Do you maybe want the schedule call in your constructor?, so:

```
def __init__(self,bot):
    self.bot = bot
    schedule.every().day.at("10:00").do(self.job)
```

I bet the main loop:

```
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

doesn't belong in the class definition either.